# Why can't I call a pointer method on a temporary object?

Tags: go, compiler-errors, standards, language-design, temporary-objects

```
type A struct{}    
func (*A) F() {}

func main() {    
    a := A{}

    a.F()      // OK
    (&a).F()   // OK

    (&A{}).F() // OK    
    A{}.F()    // Error: cannot call pointer method F on A
    (A{}).F()  // Error: cannot call pointer method F on A
}
```

**Why can't I call a pointer method on a temporary object in golang?**

Comment: Because the language specs forbids it. (Some rational: Pointer methods are used to modify the object. Modifying a temporary object is basically nonsensically.)

Comment: In the language specification clearly specifies that, the operand must be addressable. You can read it [here](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators)